# NFC - How does one implement a time limit on an NFC tag?

Tags: nfc

In order to better understand the NFC technology, I started scanning all my NFC tags. Doing so, I got stuck on the following question: how does one implement a time limit on an NFC tag?

For example, the gym I go to is using an SL2 IC2001 tag type from NXP (based on ISO/IEC 15693). When I scan it using NFC TagInfo or NFCV Reader, the only information I see is stored in block 27 (which contains a "W_OK" string). All the other blocks, which are writable, contain 0x00000000. However, according to my subscription, my NFC gym tag is suppose to deny me access to the gym at a certain date. I am not sure I understand exactly how that time limit is implemented. I realize that most of the information must be stored in their server's database, but then, what's the use of having the "W_OK" string in block 27?

As a side note, I know the data sheet provided by NXP (Smart Label IC, SL2 ICS20, Functional Specification, revision 3.1) specifies block -1, -2, -3, -4, but from what I understand, these only contain the UID (block -4 and -3), an internally used byte, EAS, AFI and DSFID (block -2) and the Write Access Conditions (block -1).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two options how to implement any access conditions, such as time limits, or also access levels (which rooms can be accessed)
* When the readers (in the Gym) are connected to a backend (=online all the time), it is usually stored in the backend.
* When the readers are not always online, it can be written in the tag (user) memory. Different vendors use different data structures here, and the data can also be password protected, or encoded in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this makes sense. I tested the tag after changing block 27's "W_OK" string to 0x00000000 and it still worked (after this change, the blocks 0 to 27 were basically all zeros). My conclusion is that the time limit conditions are obviously stored on their servers. Having said that, I still don't understand the use of the "W_OK" string.